# Text of the clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="Buttons">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(); return false;">Accept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(); return false;">Reject</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(); return false;">On Hold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(); return false;">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my script.js:

```
var myFunc = function () {
    // I want to get the Text of the link e.g. if the first list item link is
    // clicked, store "Accept" in a variable.
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass the current link as argument to the function:

```
<ul class="Buttons">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(this); return false;">Accept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(this); return false;">Reject</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(this); return false;">On Hold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunc(this); return false;">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then use the `innerHTML` property to fetch the text inside:

```
var myFunc = function (link) {
    alert(link.innerHTML);
};
```

---

UPDATE:

I haven't noticed that actually your question is tagged with jQuery. In this case I would recommend you unobtrusively subscribing to the click handler:

```
<ul class="Buttons">
    <li><a href="#">Accept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reject</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">On Hold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.Buttons a').click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE 2:

It was asked how to assign those click handlers if those anchors were dynamically generated. So let's assume that you start with the following markup:

```
<ul class="Buttons"></ul>
```

and then when some event happens (click or something) you add an anchor dynamically:

```
$('<li/>', {
    html: $('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'some text ....',
        click: myFunc
    })
}).appendTo('.Buttons');
```

where you have defined `myFunc` somewhere:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Luckily the question is tagged jQuery. :)

Comment: @Tomalak, indeed, I haven't noticed. Just couldn't believe that someone using jQuery would actually put inline onclick handlers in his markup.

Comment: Great solution. The DOM doesn't load these buttons - they are rendered by another click event, which is why I was unable to capture it by loading the click event handler in $(document).ready({}); Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Is it bad practice to have inline onclick handlers? How would I be able to capture the click for the scenario I am in?

Comment: @rabid_zombie You can delegate the events: `$(document).delegate('.Buttons li a', 'click', function () { alert($(this).text()); return false; });`. You can also change `document` to any other root element that is always present in the DOM (or at least present when the binding occurs and there-after).

Comment: @rabid_zombie, I don't know in what scenario you are. You are saying that those anchors are dynamically injected into the DOM by another click handler. In this case when you create a DOM element with jQuery you could also subscribe to its click handler. I will update my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using jQuery…

```
$("ul.buttons > li > a").click(function () {
  alert( $(this).text() );

  myFunc(this);
  return false;
});
```

…and *please* remove those `onclick` handlers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.Buttons li a').click(function(event) {
       var myVariable = $(this).text();
        alert(myVariable);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ $('.Buttons').click(function(){ alert($(this).html(); }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can bind to the elements like this:

```
//wait for document.ready to fire
$(function () {

    //find the links in the `.Button` list and bind a click event handler to them
    $('.Buttons').find('a').on('click', function () {

        //alert the text of the clicked element
        alert($(this).text());

        //prevent the normal behavior of the link, also stop the propagation of the event so no other elements fire event handlers for this event
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Your HTML would then not need any JS within it:

```
<ul class="Buttons">
    <li><a href="#">Accept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reject</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">On Hold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).text()` should work for you.