# Get value of li clicked as a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got couple of `li` elements and using them as a links to `welcome.php`. In `welcome.php` I need to know which one was clicked.

```
     <ul>
     <li><a href='welcome.php'>sport</a></li>
     <li><a href='welcome.php'>relax</a></li>
     <li><a href='welcome.php'>gym</a></li>
     </ul>
```

I can't use jquery. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037737/text-of-the-clicked-link

Comment: you can check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116929/get-clicked-li-from-ul-onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116929/get-clicked-li-from-ul-onclick) you get answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can incorporate the value in the links and get them with PHP like this

`<a href="welcome.php?x=sport">`

Where x is the variable you're going to get by using this in your php:

`$x = $_GET["x"];`

You'd need to do the same with all other links. but you only need to get the value once ofcourse

I was a little bit too late with posting this, but I think mine might have a better explaination so I'm keeping it

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this might be to append a query parameter to your links:

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="welcome.php?category=sport">sport</a></li>
 <li><a href="welcome.php?category=relax">relax</a></li>
 <li><a href="welcome.php?category=gym">gym</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have prepare one solution for you using simple html and Javascript :

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
 <li><a href='welcome.php' id="sport">sport</a></li>
 <li><a href='welcome.php' id="relax">relax</a></li>
 <li><a href='welcome.php' id="gym">gym</a></li>
</ul>
</body>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('sport');
    el.onclick = showMsg1;

    var el = document.getElementById('relax');
    el.onclick = showMsg2;

    var el = document.getElementById('gym');
    el.onclick = showMsg3;

    function showMsg1() {
      //alert('Sport Clicked!');
      //Do what ever you want after click of "sport"
      window.location = "welcome.php?type=sport";
      return false;
    }
    function showMsg2() {
      //alert('relax Clicked!');
      //Do what ever you want after click of "relax"
      window.location = "welcome.php?type=relax";
      return false;
    }
    function showMsg3() {
      //alert('Gym Clicked!');
      //Do what ever you want after click of "Gym"
      window.location = "welcome.php?type=gym";
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

I am sure this will helpful to you. Thank you :)

Comment: This won't pass which link was clicked to welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_GET for post value of li
I prepare an example for you

index.php

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="welcome.php?var=sport">sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="welcome.php?var=relax">relax</a></li>
        <li><a href="welcome.php?var=gym">gym</a></li>
    </ul>
 </form>
```

welcome.php

```
$var = $_GET["var"];
echo $var;
```